# Dynamically Create Chart and Save to File Using C# in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am trying to create a chart control at runtime and save it to file. I have no need to show the chart on the page, I am purely trying to create the chart and save it away to the file system.

My code so far is:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(int));
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Col"] = "Col1";
dr["Score"] = 10;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Col"] = "Col2";
dr["Score"] = 5;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

Chart chrt = new Chart();
ChartArea chrtArea = new ChartArea("ChartArea1");
chrtArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
chrtArea.Area3DStyle.WallWidth = 0;
chrt.ChartAreas.Add(chrtArea);
Series series = new Series("Series1");
series.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
series.XValueMember = "Col";
series.YValueMembers = "Score";

chrt.DataSource = dt;
chrt.DataBind();

//Using MemoryStream to bypass permissions issue that I can investigate at another stage
using (MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    chrt.SaveImage(imgStream, ChartImageFormat.Gif);
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"PATH_TO_FOLDER\img.gif", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        imgStream.WriteTo(file);
    }
}
```

The image saves to file but is blank. This is what I get: [image: Chart Image]

Is this because the chart is not actually rendering or am I doing something monumentally stupid?

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that no sooner had I added the question, I spotted what I was doing wrong!

I have added the following it works :)

```
chrt.Series.Add(series);
```

I wasn't adding the `series` to the chart!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the snippet to save chart image in your file system.

```
Chart1.SaveImage(Server.MapPath("Folder Name to save image") + "\\" + "Sample143.jpeg");
```